# not sure why while loop isn't looping

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to prompt the user to enter 5 integers but it won't loop more than once. I don't know why this is happening and couldn't resolve the error by myself

#### Code:

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);

        int counter= 0;
        Boolean inputOK;
        int iInput;

        int data[]= new int[5];

       // while (counter<5);

     do {

         System.out.println(" Please enter an integer");

         while (!s.hasNextInt()) {
             System.out.println("Invalid input");
             System.out.println("Please Enter an integer value");
             s.next();}

            iInput=s.nextInt();

             if (iInput < -10 || iInput > 10) {
                 System.out.println("Not a valid integer. Please enter a integer between -10 and 10");
                 inputOK = false;
             } else {
                 inputOK = true;

             }

         System.out.println("before while loop"+ inputOK);
         } while (!inputOK);
        counter++;
        System.out.println("counter value is"+ counter);



     }
}
```

Comment: You have a counter, but you don't have a loop that uses it. It looks like you started to write one and then commented it out.

Comment: Note that there is no need to use a `do while` loop for this task, you can use a simple `while loop`. Also this `while (!inputOK);` will cause your code to get stuck and loop infinitely if your `inputOK` is false. Lastly, you only enter one int, so the loop will only run once `while (!s.hasNextInt())` ...

Comment: Hi Kevin and welcome to SO. I would recommend making it a habbit to use proper indentation. Not only is it crucial for writing functioning code, it's also the basis for communicating with others about your code (like on SO, but also later in your professional life, when many others will be reading your code)

Answer (score 0):

If you follow your code, you can see that when `inputOK` is `true`, there is no loop to get back to. It looks like you had some counter in mind, but you ended up not using it. The following code does what I think you intended with your code:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] data = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    
    // Skip over non-integers.
    while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input: " + sc.next());
    }
    
    // Read and store the integer if it is valid.
    int nextInt = sc.nextInt();
    if(nextInt < -10 || nextInt > 10) {
        
        // Make the for loop repeat this iteration.
        System.out.println("Not a valid integer. Please enter an integer between -10 and 10.");
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    data[i] = nextInt;
}
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("data[" + i + "] = " + data[i]);
}
```